# Replace Autoprefixer browsers option to Browserslist

Tags: metronic, gulp-autoprefixer

i am using [Metronic v6.03]

I followed the Quick Start  tutorial on documentation.
https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=docs

If I give in the command ‘gulp build’ I get a message :

“Replace Autoprefixer browsers option to Browserslist config.
Use browserslist key in package.json or .browserslistrc file.

Using browsers option cause some error. Browserslist config
can be used for Babel, Autoprefixer, postcss-normalize and other tools.

If you really need to use option, rename it to overrideBrowserslist.

Learn more at:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#readme
[https://twitter.com/browserslist”](https://twitter.com/browserslist%E2%80%9D)

The Theme don’t compiles correctly.

NPM version : 6.9.0

Yarn version : 1.16.0

Gulp version

CLI : 2.2.0

Local version : 4.0.2

I changed the line browserlist at package.json to

"browserslist": [

```
"last 1 version",

"> 1%",

"maintained node versions",

"not dead"
```

]

and try to replace the line with :

"browserslist": [

```
"defaults"
```

]

On Linux I added a file .browserslistrc with the lines above.

Answer (score 27):

The problem will be in `gulpfile.js`.

Look for `autoprefixer()`, this function will have some options passed as parameter. Remove those options. And move them to your `package.json` as `browserslist: ["browserConfig1", "browserConfig2", "..."`].

Comment: as per example https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist-example

Answer (score 6):

Go to the helpers.js file and at line 128, 
you must change the browsers option to overrideBrowserslist. then it will work

Answer (score 3):

You can create .browserslistrc instead of editing package.json:

`last 1 version`

`>1%`

`maintained node versions`

`not dead`
`